# Entering numbers in program using while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, input, while-loop

I am a beginner in Java, can somebody please explain me how the total is 11.

Question - The user is ready to enter in these numbers one by one until the program stops: 
4 7 5 8 9 3 4 1 5 3 5

What is displayed as the total?

```
int number;
int total = 0;
System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt();
while (number != 1)
{
if (number < 5) total = total + number;
System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain step by step.

**Step - 1:**

You've declared two integer variables. One for holding the input, and another for holding the total value after your calculation. The integer `total` is initialized as 0. The following part of your code is doing this:

```
int number;
int total = 0;
```

**Step - 2:**

Now you're providing input values. Then the input values are entering the while loop. The while loop will continue to execute unless your input value is **1**. Your first input is **4**, 4!=1, so, it enters the loop.

```
System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt();
while (number != 1)
{
```

**Step - 3:**

Now, inside your loop, you're checking whether your input value is less than 5 or not. *If* it's less than 5, then `total` value will be incremented to `total + number`. *Else*, `total` remains unchanged. Regardless of the if condition, your system will continue to prompt you to provide `number` inputs as long as it's not 1. The following code does this:

```
  if (number < 5) total = total + number;
  System.out.print("Enter a number");
  number = input.nextInt();
}
```

In this case, your input sequence is **4 7 5 8 9 3 4 1 5 3 5**.

For first input **4**, 4 < 5, which is `true`, so `total = 0 + 4 = 4`. The next input is **7**, 7 < 5 is `false`, so `total` remains 4, same goes for inputs **5** through **9**. When your input is **3**, 3 < 5 is `true`, so `total = 4 + 3 = 7`. Then for input **4**, 4 < 5 is `true` again, so `total = 7 + 4 = 11`

As we've already seen, the above while loop will terminate, as soon as you input **1**. Your next input is **1**, so the loop will terminate, you can't input any more number, and your final total value remains **11**.

**Step - 4:**

Outside the loop, you're printing the value of `total`, so it will display 11.

```
System.out.println(total);
```

**p.s.**

If you understood my solution, your next task will be to do the exact same thing using `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

your while loop will run until it gets 1 as input.

```
while (number != 1)
```

Inside while loop you have a if clause it will add your input to total when entered number is less than 5

```
if (number < 5) total = total + number;
```

that's why only adds 4, 3, 4 and total=11

Answer (score 0):

You are entering `4 7 5 8 9 3 4 1 5 3 5`

The following code only allows `4 7 5 8 9 3 4` to be accepted cause it breaks from the loop when `1` is entered.

```
while (number != 1)
{
...
}
```

More over the following code only adds `4 3 4` because number should be less than 5

```
if (number < 5) total = total + number;
```

Hence you get 4 + 3 + 4 = 11

Answer (score 0):

While loop will run till the user enters 1.
And the numbers will sum up if the number entered is less than 5.
So from what the user has entered, it will be 4+3+4 = 11. At 1, the while loop will exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number;
int total = 0;
System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt();
while (number != 1)
{
if (number < 5) total = total + number;

// only adds 4 3 4 because number should be less than 5

System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(total);

// Because of that you can: 4+3+4 = 11
```

Comment: Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is **4 7 5 8 9 3 4 1 5 3 5**

Your code snippet with explanation as comment is given below:

```
int number;
int total = 0;
System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt(); // your first input number ie. 4 is taken as input
while (number != 1) // while starts because 4 > 1
{
if (number < 5) total = total + number; 
System.out.print("Enter a number");
number = input.nextInt();

 /* in while loop only 4,3,4 will be added to the total because you have **if (number < 5) total = total + number;**  loop will break after taking input 1 because of  **while (number != 1)**. At that time total will be equal to 11. */

}
System.out.println(total); // outside loop value of total = 11 will be printed
```